# Error installing Python on my Windows 64-bit Machine

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows

I am on a 64-bit Intel Core i3 7th generation machine. I installed python there and after which when I typed `python` on the command line to make sure that it is properly installed I found that it has installed the 32 bit version of the same. The shell prompt displayed something like this - `MSC v.1916 32 bit (Intel)] on win32`.
Is it fine or is there some issue which can be fixed?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: i think it's better you install python with CMD to install that

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to [python web-site](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/) and download windows x86-64 executable installer and then run the installation again. Make sure the installation wizard shows you 64-bit Setup.

After the installation complete you might have to check the windows environmental variables(go to Control Panel - System and Security - System, here you need to select Advanced system settings and go to Environment variables) to point a variable to a new x64 folder.

After that when you start python from the cmd or PowerShell, you should see that you are running a 64-bit version of it.

Answer (score 0):

There could be only a single problem that is the performance. Else everything will go good.
The speed may be a bit low.
Anyway you can simply uninstall the 32 bit and install 64 bit if you want.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download the 64-bit installation file to install 64-bit Python.
The 32-bit and 64-bit installation files are different.
Be sure to install the 64-bit file.